# Implementing a one to zero or one relationship in SQL

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

Let us say that I am designing a database for a scenario where there exists a one-to-zero-or-one (1-0..1) relationship. For example:

- There is a set of *Users*, and **some** *Users* may also be *Customers*.

Thus, I created the two corresponding tables, `users` and `customers`, but…

…What is the best way to represent and implement this situation in a given SQL platform? I have considered two possible solutions:

1. In the `users` table, add the `customer` column which may be either a FOREIGN KEY
   reference to `customers` or a `NULL` mark.
2. In the `customers` table, include a `user` column (set with a `UNIQUE` constraint) which points to the `users` table.

I have already asked a similar question in some forums, but the answer
was basically “whatever you need”, “whatever you think convenient”. I
do not like this kind of answer. I want a serious piece of DB theory
instead, a well founded answer. Where can I read about 1-0..1
relationships?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I want a serious piece of DB theory

Modern relational theory [rejects nulls](https://web.archive.org/web/20120114081039/http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/1706814.htm), which would seem to immediately invalidate your option 1. However, this strawman may be eliminated by replacing the default null with a default value e.g. a 'dummy' customer created solely to explicitly model the "is not a customer" correspondence.

I think your option 2 is the most theoretically sound because, unlike the modified option 1, the relations can be in sixth normal form (6NF), being a projection-join normal form and the highest normal form attainable.

I have also heard of a design rule of thumb that states that a relation should model EITHER an entity OR the relationship between entities but never both, which seems sensible to me. Again, this would favour option 2. However, I heard of this rule of thumb many years ago, don't recall where and can offer no serious theoretical basis (other than 6NF as mentioned above).

Answer (score 3):

You have been given the correct answer in part.  The real answer comes from your data model and how it got normalized.  A key is how you get to the relationship:

- The `customers` table consists of a number of fields considered for the `users` table which belong to the the customer concept, and are null unless the user is also a customer (sub-type of user).  In this case the `customers` table inherits the primary key from the `users` table.  (It is possible to multiple sub-types which may or may not overlap.)
- The `customers` table consists of a number of fields related to the customer concept, but not necessarily the user concept.  The customer is a strong table and is not dependent on the user concept. (Removing the `users` table would not significantly impact the design of the customers table.) In this case the customers table gets its own primary key.

What you are have is a special case of optional one to many relationship where the upper bound is 1.  Consider it from both sides:  Would it be possible for one user to have multiple customers, or one customer to have multiple users?  If so, you will need to remodel your data.

Adding the `user-id` foreign key to the `customers` table could be considered a better choice as correctly maps the one to many (upper limit 1) relationship and avoids a nullable field.  To enforce the upper limit the foreign key index needs to be unique.  This will occur automatically if the primary key is the `user-id`.

Adding the `customer-id` as an optional foreign key to the `users` table enforces the upper limit of 1 in the relationship but reverses the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a little more complex but flexible approach.  The parent table is "person" (or "entity" depending on how complex you want to be).  Then the customer table and user table each have a FK to the person table.
The person table contains personal details while the customer and user tables contain only attributes associated with a user or customer.
Often addresses (email and snail mail), phone numbers, etc. are also represented in separate tables with mapping tables to permit many-to-many situations.
This is a relatively common model which you can find on a number of reference sites.